# `M-%` is interpreted as `M-5` (prefix arg of 5)

Tags: keystrokes

On one of my machines the query replace key sequence (`M-%`) isn't recognized, and is instead recognized as `M-5`, which acts as a numeric prefix argument of 5 (e.g. inserts 5 copies of the next character I type).

How do I begin looking for what is interrupting this functionality? So far I have tried running `emacs -q` to see if my init file was broken, but no luck.

Comment: I assume you're pressing and holding the `Shift` key while pressing the keyboard `5` key, and that `Shift`+`5` for your keyboard should produce a `%` character. Do you see the same problem outside Emacs, or is it just Emacs that does not shift the `5` keyboard key when you press the `Shift` key?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have no problems producing `%` in other contexts.

I wonder if some system shortcut could be interfering with the sequence? I am running MX Linux 17, and haven't tooled around too much with the default shortcuts.